# I have an svg element that i want to alter the color of with a button click. Involves, json, and csv

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, svg, d3.js

What this code does is create a map projection using g.selectAll("path)... It then assigns small circles to the perimeters of associated countries.  What I want to be able to do is create buttons in the html file that when pressed will "select"/"deselect" or color/uncolor the circles and/or associated countries. Basically I want to be able to choose what countries and circles are colored.  I know how to create buttons and reference them and such, calling functions with them. My hangup is that I am not sure how to get the svg or g element to redraw or reupdate the canvas. If i debug, it shows the call stack not going into the g.selectAll more than once even with the method executes multiple times. First time writing js so forgive any inconsistencies or rough code outline.Thanks!

```
var svg = d3.select("#container").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("g");



//Create secondary layer to canvas SVG

var g = svg.append("g");

function buildMap() {    



d3.json("countries.geo.json", function(json) {  
d3.csv("Map_of_the_Gods.csv", function(data) {
    // Go through each element of the csv

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        // Get data for csv element
        var csvName = data[i].name;
        var csvCulture = data[i].culture;
        var csvLocation = data[i].location;
        var csvGender = data[i].gender;
        var csvSpecies  = data[i].species;
        var csvType = data[i].type;
        var csvWikiLink = data[i].linkwik;
        var csvGCLink = data[i].linkgc;
        var csvPicture = data[i].picture;


        // Go through each element of the json looking for a country
        //      to match the country of the csv.
        for (var j = 0; j < json.features.length; j++) {
            var jsonCountry = json.features[j].properties.name;
            //console.log(jsonCountry);
            //console.log(j);
            if (csvLocation == jsonCountry) {
                // Assign the color retrieved from the csv to the
                //      matching json element.
                json.features[j].properties.Name = csvName;
                json.features[j].properties.Culture = csvCulture;
                json.features[j].properties.Location = csvLocation;
                json.features[j].properties.Gender = csvGender;
                json.features[j].properties.Species = csvSpecies;
                json.features[j].properties.Type = csvType;
                json.features[j].properties.WikiLink = csvWikiLink;
                json.features[j].properties.Picture = csvPicture;
                json.features[j].properties.initialColor = 1;


                break;
            }//if(csvLocation == jsonCountry
        }//for loop
    }//outer for loop

    g.selectAll("path")
     .data(json.features)
     .enter()
     .append("path")
     .attr("d", path)
     .style("fill", function(d) {
        var country = d.properties.Location;
        var colorChange = d.properties.initialColor;

        if( country === "Mexico") {
            console.log("yo");
                return "#410d66";}//purple           
        if(country === "Greece") {
               return "#000072";}//aqua
        if(country === "Japan") {
               return "#c90e0e";}//red
        if(country === "United Kingdom") {
               return "#194719";}
        if(country === "Ireland") {
               return "#194719";}//green        
        if(country === "Nigeria") {
               return "#ff9900";}//light brown
        if(country === "Peru") {
               return "#85ad33";}//green yellow
        if(country === "Egypt") {
               return "#ff5050";}//salmony
        if(country === "Denmark") {
               return "#75A3A3";}//bluegrey
        if(country === "Finland") {
               return "#75A3A3";}
        if(country === "Norway") {
               return "#75A3A3";}
        if(country === "Sweden") {
               return "#75A3A3";}
        else {
            return "grey";}
    });//This is for the stlye attribute for the path

   // g.selectAll("circle").remove();
 //We will now create all of the circles and Gods
    g.selectAll("circle")
     .data(data)
     .enter()
     .append("circle")
     .attr("cx", function(d) {
            return projection([d.lon,d.lat])[0];})
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
            return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[1];})
      .attr("r", 3)
      .style("fill", function(d) {
                var typeOfGod = d.type;

                if(typeOfGod === "Storm" ) {
                    return "yellow";}
                else if(typeOfGod ==="Sky"){
                    return "#87CEFA";}
                else if(typeOfGod === "Death" || typeOfGod ==="Chaos") {
                    return "black";}
                else if(typeOfGod === "Agriculture") {
                    return "#006300";}
                else if(typeOfGod === "Motherhood") {
                    return "#99FF99";}
                else if(typeOfGod === "War" ) {
                    return "#9e0e0e";}
                else if(typeOfGod === "Moon") {
                    return "white";}
                else if(typeOfGod === "Sun") {
                    return "orange";}
                else if(typeOfGod === "Love") {
                    return "#ff99ff";}
                else if(typeOfGod ===  "Wisdom") {
                    return "#9900ff";}
                else if(typeOfGod === "Sea") {
                    return "blue";}

                else{
                    return "grey";}

            })//These brackets match to the style for circles and end the selectALL()

     .on('mouseover', function(d) {
        tooltip.transition()
               .duration(400)
               .style("opacity", 0);
        tooltip.transition()
               .duration(100)
               .style("fill", "black")
               .style("opacity", ".9");
        tooltip.html("<img src = " + d.picture+">" + "<br>" + "Name: " + d.name + "<br>"
                     + "Type: " + d.type + "<br>" 
                    + "Culture: " + d.culture + "<br>" + "Region: " + d.location + "<br>"
                    + "Gender: " + d.gender + "<br>" + "Species: " + d.species + "<br>" +
                    '<a href = "' + d.linkwik + '">' + "Wikipedia" + "</a>" + "<br>"
                    + '<a href = "' + d.linkgc + '">' +"GodChecker" + "</a>")
               .style("left", (d3.event.pageX ) + "px")
               .style("top", (d3.event.pageY) + "px")});



    });//These bracets are for d3.csv line above
});//These brackets are for d3.json line
//THis is the bracket for the function countriesSelect
```

Comment: I am able to reference the values of the button's being pressed or not, and I have tried passing them to the function above(with argument) with success. So i am able to reference the buttons, I just need their states to determine the colors being drawn. I have tried pretty much every thing over the last 5-6 hours.

Comment: Just add to your circle selection: .on("click", function(d) {... do whatever you want to do (like with your tooltip) });

Comment: I probably should clarify, unless somethings going over my head, I'm going to add some buttons below the canvas. One would be called moon for example. I want to be able to click that button and have that color or de-color al circles associated with moon. If moon is white, and on, when i click the button I want them to all turn grey(off) then turn back on with another press.

Comment: Why can't you create a global boolean variable toggleMoon and call in the moon button's event handler : g.selectAll("circle).style("fill", toggleMoon ? "white" ; "grey"); toggleMoon != toggleMoon;. Alternataively you could check for the current fill color and set the fill accordingly